# Strange behavior while destroying activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash

I'm getting crash reports which is very strange to me.

Here is a part of the stacktrace.

```
foo.bar.TagFragment1.onCreateView
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState$2563266
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy
com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onDestroy
foo.bar.BaseFragmentActivity.onDestroy
```

Can anyone explain how does it possible that FragmentManage calls performCreateView while the activity is destroying.

The activity is actually a sherlock activity with FragmentTabHost and a bunch of tabs.

Any help would be greatfull

Comment: is der any exception??..if yes..what is it??..

Comment: @bakriOnFire its NPE in my custom view and it does not conform to the topic of the question.